# How to create an integration test with multiple instances

Tags: go, integration-testing

I am trying to write tests (mainly integration tests) for my project.
But the problem is I have many modes that are working with each other.

[image: cmd folder]

When trying to run the system I try running these:

```
go run main.go http
go run main.go tasks
go run main.go scheduler
```

In my integration test I need all these instances to be up. Data flow is like belew:

1. A request comes to http node
2. Http node passes request to tasks via Redis queue
3. Scheduler node checks every 30 seconds if X logics happened and saves the status in database (written in Gorm)

how should I produce these dependencies (running 3 nodes with mysql, redis services) for my integration test

Comment: It's not clear what "an instance", "a mode" and "a dependency" are. Judging from the name "cmd", I conjure you build a binary (an execulable image file) which can be run in different modes, like, `./binary serve-http [options]`, `./binary scheduler [options]`, and so on; am I correct? If yes, are there any special requirements for running these processes–like, say, you have to run them as Docker containers etc, or is it possible to "just" run them as normal processes?

Comment: @kostix Thanks for your answer, I edited the question and made it more clear. Let me know if there is more unclear parts

Comment: Yes, it's pretty clear now. But first let's deal with `go run`: please never ever run `go run` for anything except toy examples of throw-away script-like code. Implementing `go run` was actually a mistake which trips lots of people who have no exposure to compiled languages. The two contemporary full-fledged implementations of Go, one of which you're ostensibly using, rely on [AOT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation), and `go run` merely calls `go build`, then runs the result and then throws it away. That is not how Go code is supposed to work in production.

Comment: As to the essense of your question, it's practically unanswerable because your problem has lots of solutions. A typical one is to write a small set of helper code to run (and stop) processes, which would usually use `os/exec`, and then merely make use of that code (you can call it "a framework", or "a library", if you want) to start a set of processes with proper configuration (such as command-line options, envionment variables, configuration files and whatnot–whatever those commands use for its configuration) and then make them interact with one another.

Comment: You will also have to collect their logs.

Comment: One more note: all said above supposes you already have running mysql, redis and whatnot sorted out (say, in your CI setup). If not, and you also want to ask how to run those programs as well, then you either have to write code for them as well or maybe think about _orchestration_ (in your CI maybe). In the simplest case this could arguably be [Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). We use it at my $dayjob for precisely the sort of tasks like this one being discussed.